# Import nested Json into cassandra

Tags: java, python, json, cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have list of nested Json objects which I want to save into cassandra (1.2.15).

However the constraint I have is that I do not know the column family's column data types before hand i.e each Json object has got a different structure with fields of different datatypes.

So I am planning to use dynamic composite type for creating a column family.

So I would like to know if there is an API or suggest some ideas on how to save such Json object list into cassandra.

Thanks

Comment: What JSON library are you using? (and btw why both python or Java?)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to be able to query individual items from the json structure, just store the whole serialized string into one column.

If you do need to be able to query individual items, I suggest using one of the collection types: list, set, or map.  As far as typing goes, I would leave the value as text or blob and rely on json to handle the typing.  In other words, json encode the values before inserting and then json decode the values when reading.